# Basic Question about notation in the space of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading the book "Introduction to Calculus of Variations" by Bernard Dacorogna (Could not find a link in google books) where he defines
$C(\bar{\Omega})$ to be the space of continuous functions $u : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ which can be continuously extended to $\bar{\Omega}$ (here $\Omega$
is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

After this, he defines the norm over $C(\bar{\Omega})$ by 
$\|u\|_0 = \sup_{x \in \bar{\Omega}} |u(x)|$ and then $C(\bar{\Omega})$ with this norm is a Banach Space.

I am confused about two things:-

1) Does $C(\bar{\Omega})$ consist of functions $u : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ which can be continuously extended or functions $u : \bar{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}$

2)The "norm" $\|.\|_0$ is not a norm as $\bar{\Omega}$ need not be bounded and
hence it can take an infinite value

Can someone please let me know if I am right and if so, this notation is OK in some texts.

Comment: 1) A continuous function $u:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ which can be extended continuously to $\overline \Omega$ has a unique continuous extension. Therefore, $C(\overline\Omega)\sim C(\Omega)$, if we denote the functions which can be continuously extended by $C(\Omega)$. 2) Maybe he means to allow only bounded continuous functions, i.e. only functions for which the norm is bounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I included a screenshot below. The concept of $C(\overline{\Omega})$ is unambigious, as user161825 pointed out. If a continuous extension to the closure exists, it is unique and we may consider the function as already  extended.

Item 2) is a mess-up on the author's part. Just assume $\Omega$ is a bounded open set, because it will be practically everywhere in the book.

<sup>I might add that this is not a book I would recommend for learning the calculus of variations. The variational chapters in Brezis and Evans would be a better source, partly because they are better written, partly because they are not laser-beam focused on the Italian tradition of the subject.</sup>

---

[image: definition]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion. I could not find any book by Brezis and Evans, could you give the title of the book. Thanks.

Comment: @jpv Those are two different books. Evans _Partial differential equations_ and Brezis _Functional Analysis, Sobolev spaces_...

Comment: In the second edition of the book, it seems the functions are assumed to be bounded, as user161825 pointed out.